# Average days between multiple date time using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I would like to get average days between multiple datetime values using Jquery/Javascript.

following are my samples data :

```
8/8/2017 1:58 AM  
8/3/2017 1:58 AM  
8/4/2017 2:18 AM  
8/5/2017 1:58 AM  
8/7/2017 1:58 AM  
7/25/2017 1:58 AM  
7/24/2017 1:58 AM  
7/18/2017 1:58 AM  
7/25/2017 1:58 AM  
8/1/2017 1:58 AM
```

Here's my attempt logic :

```js
var sum = ['7/21/2017 1:58 AM','8/3/2017 1:58 AM','8/5/2017 1:58 AM','8/8/2017 1:58 AM'];

var avgval = "";
var total = 0
for(var index=0; index<sum.length; index++){
if (index < (sum.length-1)){
   console.log(sum[index+1], sum[index])
   var days = Math.abs((new Date(sum[index+1])-new Date(sum[index]))/(1000*60*60*24));
   total+=days;
}
else{
    avgval = total / sum.length-1;
}
}
console.log(avgval);
```

Comment: You question is not clear. How exactly are you planning to get an average from this? Median between first/last? Also, please show the JS code you wrote yourself to attempt this. As it stands this question is too broad so is likely to be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself, please show us

Comment: ok you want average days. Did you try anything?

Comment: Is that a math problem?

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan for your quick update and down vote, I updated my question so it could be more clear.

Comment: I did not downvote. I was trying to be helpful and give you information about how you should improve your question if you want some worthwhile answers. I can downvote if you'd like.

Comment: What is your definition of `days between` for dates, that are not ordered in ascending or descending order. 5-10-8 distances are 5 and 2 or 5 and -2?

Comment: Why don't you just find the duration between the earliest and latest date and divide it by `array.length - 1`..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `moment.js` too to calculate difference in days (days are rounded down to integers).

```
var sum = 0;
var prevdate = false;

for(var k in dates) {
  var thedate = moment(dates[k], "M/D/YYYY H:mm A");
  if(prevdate) {
    sum += prevdate.diff(thedate, 'days');
  }
  prevdate = thedate;
}

var avg = (sum / (dates.length - 1));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ishukshin/s6q0rhzL/

**As for your update**

You should use parentheses when dividing: `avgval = total / (sum.length-1)`

You have to define difference in days. Maybe you'll need to add `Math.abs` for a difference between dates.

Comment: why aren't they ordered by increasing date? This leads to negative distance.

Comment: Are you criticising your own answer?

Comment: I'm criticising a set of dates, provided by the author.

Comment: Thanks @shukshin.ivan I used maths.abs instead of maths.round and seem to working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple for loop and then use this function to get difference time between two dates :

```
 let difference = (new Date(mytime1).getTime() - new Date(mytime2).getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);
```

But be careful , it will return difference in millisecond so you have to divide it by (1000*60*60*24)

After you save all difference between date you divide it by there number

Comment: I don't know where you copied this code from, but I don't see how it's in any way relevant to the OP

Comment: That still doesn't make it relevant to the OPs issue of finding an average between dates.

Comment: The main idea to find differences between date in milliseconds  then find the average  for these differences. it make seance